# Python reading specific csv column into list

Tags: python, file, csv

I have a csv file with 3 columns.  I'd like to read the file and put column number 2 into a list.

I currently have it reading the file and putting all three columns as tuples into a list:

```
    import csv


    with open ('list.csv', 'rb') as f:
           reader = csv.reader(f)
           the_list = map(tuple, reader)


    print the_list
```

output =      [('1', 'bob', '23'), ('2', 'jane', '21')]

whereas I want the output list to be [('bob'), ('jane')] and I'm uncertain of how to do it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  list comprehension.

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
print [i[1] for i in reader]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('jjon.csv', 'rU') as infile:

    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    print [i[0] for i in reader]
```